# How Do I get booting log for U-boot

Tags: linux-kernel, bootloader, u-boot

I know I can get Linux booting log using dmesg command but don't know how can get booting log of U-boot when my system just started.I Tried Go-ogling also but all I got is dmesg reference everywhere.

Also I am not sure what is CRM in U-boot?
I am on ARM based target board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console output from U-Boot is not saved anywhere (by default).
Hence, there is no "log" is display.
You have to capture U-Boot's console messages as they are output (e.g. using a terminal emulation program's logging feature), or they are gone forever.

> Also I am not sure what is CRTM in U-boot?

"CRTM" is not standard terminology for U-Boot AFAIK.
It probably refers to a [secure bootstrap program](http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2004/af-congdon-tcg-overview-1104.pdf) that loads U-Boot.